# python classmethod complains when called

Tags: python, autobahn

I have a classmethod:

```
class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    @classmethod
    def send(cls, text):
        cls.sendMessage(cls, text)

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        msp=MyServerProtocol
        msp.send('test')
```

I am trying to call this classmethod (as a test for now, from within the class)  and I am getting:

```
exceptions.TypeError: unbound method sendMessage() must be called with MyServerProtocol instance as first argument (got type instance instead)
```

It is expecting an instance and complaining that it got an instance... Anyone know how to correctly call this.  Once I get it working I can test from within another class, just want to get it working first before I migrate.

EDIT:

I have modified my code to call the method as follows but it is still now working.

```
class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):

        myInput = literal_eval(payload)
        cg = coreg.DataGatherCg()
        cg.test(myInput, self)


    def send(self, text):
        self.sendMessage(text)

class DataGatherCg():

    def test(self, myInput, obj):
        obj.send(myInput)
```

SendMessage from AutoBahn is as follows, after passing self I am getting an assertionError:

```
def sendMessage(self,
                payload,
                isBinary=False,
                fragmentSize=None,
                sync=False,
                doNotCompress=False):
    """
    Implements :func:`autobahn.websocket.interfaces.IWebSocketChannel.sendMessage`
    """
    assert(type(payload) == bytes)

    if self.state != WebSocketProtocol.STATE_OPEN:
        return

    if self.trackedTimings:
        self.trackedTimings.track("sendMessage")

    # (initial) frame opcode
    #
    if isBinary:
        opcode = 2
    else:
        opcode = 1

    self.trafficStats.outgoingWebSocketMessages += 1

    # setup compressor
    #
    if self._perMessageCompress is not None and not doNotCompress:
        sendCompressed = True

        self._perMessageCompress.startCompressMessage()

        self.trafficStats.outgoingOctetsAppLevel += len(payload)

        payload1 = self._perMessageCompress.compressMessageData(payload)
        payload2 = self._perMessageCompress.endCompressMessage()
        payload = b''.join([payload1, payload2])

        self.trafficStats.outgoingOctetsWebSocketLevel += len(payload)

    else:
        sendCompressed = False
        l = len(payload)
        self.trafficStats.outgoingOctetsAppLevel += l
        self.trafficStats.outgoingOctetsWebSocketLevel += l

    # explicit fragmentSize arguments overrides autoFragmentSize setting
    #
    if fragmentSize is not None:
        pfs = fragmentSize
    else:
        if self.autoFragmentSize > 0:
            pfs = self.autoFragmentSize
        else:
            pfs = None

    # send unfragmented
    #
    if pfs is None or len(payload) <= pfs:
        self.sendFrame(opcode=opcode, payload=payload, sync=sync, rsv=4 if sendCompressed else 0)

    # send data message in fragments
    #
    else:
        if pfs < 1:
            raise Exception("payload fragment size must be at least 1 (was %d)" % pfs)
        n = len(payload)
        i = 0
        done = False
        first = True
        while not done:
            j = i + pfs
            if j > n:
                done = True
                j = n
            if first:
                self.sendFrame(opcode=opcode, payload=payload[i:j], fin=done, sync=sync, rsv=4 if sendCompressed else 0)
                first = False
            else:
                self.sendFrame(opcode=0, payload=payload[i:j], fin=done, sync=sync)
            i += pfs

    # if self.debug:
    #   self.log.debug("Traffic statistics:\n" + str(self.trafficStats))
```

Comment: You need to show the definition of `sendMessage`, since that is the method that is raising the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendMessage` looks like it is an instance method, requiring that it be bound to an instance, to illustrate, the following should work:

```
class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        msp=MyServerProtocol
        self.sendMessage('test')
```

Comment: how can i call sendMessage outside of that class?

Comment: you need a reference to an isntance that has `sendMessage`, you could pass around self?

Comment: Tried it and i get a different error at least, now I am getting an 'exceptions.AssertionError'  the assert is called within autobahn/websocket/protocol.py

Comment: Assertion error was because I was passing a dictionary instead of a string, passing self did solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The error can't be reproduced with your minimal sample, but it seems to be saying that `sendMessage()` is not a class method. You can't call instance methods from class methods without also passing the instance itself.

Try adding another argument for `send()` that will hold the instance and then pass `self` in for that argument. Something like:

```
class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    @classmethod
    def send(cls, self, text):
        self.sendMessage(text)

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        msp=MyServerProtocol
        msp.send(self, 'test')
```

Though at this point, you might as well just make `send()` an instance method.

Comment: Did not work, complaining of str instance instead. Basically my goal is to use self.sendMessage('stuff') in other classes, but I am not able to do that

Comment: But where would that message be sent? Is there a single server connection that has `sendMessage()` method? If that's the case, you're looking for a singleton.